# My ad tableviewcell is unclickable, but the ad shows up

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, admob, native-ads

My ad shows up on the tableviewcell, but for some reason I cannot navigate to the apps website when I click the ad, why is that?
Here is my code in cellforrowat function:

```
let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("NativeAdTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! NativeAdTableViewCell
            
            cell.img.isHidden = false
            cell.install.isHidden = false
            cell.adSubtitle.isHidden = false
            cell.adTitle.text = ad?.headline
            cell.adSubtitle.text = ad?.body
            cell.img.image = ad?.icon?.image
            ad?.rootViewController = self
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCell.SelectionStyle.none
            cell.vie.nativeAd = ad
            return cell
```

Here is my code in adload function:

```
nativeAd.delegate = self
    ad = nativeAd
    tableVie.reloadData()
```

Here is my code in tableviewcell class:

```
install.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
```

Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: That is install here? maybe install.isUserInteractionEnabled = true << you should use? Why you disable here the user interaction?